# How to install missing resampling methods in GDAL Warp (QGIS)?

Tags: qgis, gdalwarp

I am trying to resample my data based on "sum" resampling method. But unfortunately, I do not see this in the drop down menu in Warp.I am running a GDAl version 3.1, but it does not have this function. Can someone please help me figure out how to "install" this?
[image]

Comment: 3.16.7-Hannover

Comment: Make a QGIS feature request about adding the new option into the menu. Meanwhile use gdalwarp directly from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

The method is not in the GUI but you may patch manually the file `warp.py` as it should be in a path similar to `processing/algs/gdal/warp.py`

The following code

```py
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.methods = ((self.tr('Nearest Neighbour'), 'near'),
                        (self.tr('Bilinear'), 'bilinear'),
                        (self.tr('Cubic'), 'cubic'),
                        (self.tr('Cubic Spline'), 'cubicspline'),
                        (self.tr('Lanczos Windowed Sinc'), 'lanczos'),
                        (self.tr('Average'), 'average'),
                        (self.tr('Mode'), 'mode'),
                        (self.tr('Maximum'), 'max'),
                        (self.tr('Minimum'), 'min'),
                        (self.tr('Median'), 'med'),
                        (self.tr('First Quartile'), 'q1'),
                        (self.tr('Third Quartile'), 'q3'))
```

could be changed

```py
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.methods = ((self.tr('Nearest Neighbour'), 'near'),
                        (self.tr('Bilinear'), 'bilinear'),
                        (self.tr('Cubic'), 'cubic'),
                        (self.tr('Cubic Spline'), 'cubicspline'),
                        (self.tr('Lanczos Windowed Sinc'), 'lanczos'),
                        (self.tr('Average'), 'average'),
                        (self.tr('Mode'), 'mode'),
                        (self.tr('Maximum'), 'max'),
                        (self.tr('Minimum'), 'min'),
                        (self.tr('Median'), 'med'),
                        (self.tr('First Quartile'), 'q1'),
                        (self.tr('Third Quartile'), 'q3'))
        if GdalUtils.version() >= 3010000:
            self.methods = list(self.methods)
            self.methods.append((self.tr('Sum'), 'sum'))
            self.methods = tuple(self.methods)
```

PS: to keep a tuple, I cast it to a list to append Sum method and convert it back to tuple. Quite dirty...

A similar method could be applied for `rms` sampling method but testing GDAL version to 3.3 and using `insert` to get the same position in the list as the documentation (https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html)

If it was a PR, I would also need to look at translation of the new string to be translated maybe.